# How to echo <?php ?>

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok, so I'm basically trying to combine two php codes into one.

First code (identifying a specific author's name and giving a special style):

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('display_name') === 'daveMClaren') {
echo "<b><a href='https://www.homepage.com/author/" . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . "'>" . esc_html(get_the_author()) . "</a></b>";
} else {
echo get_the_author();
} ?>
```

Second code (if custom field is available, show it):

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-author', true ) ) {
echo  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-author', true   ); 
} else {
echo get_the_author();
} ?>
```

Both codes works great.

Now I want to do this:

If an author's name identified, show it with a style,
else, echo the second code.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('display_name') === 'daveMClaren') {
echo "<b><a href='https://www.homepage.com/author/" . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . "'>" . esc_html(get_the_author()) . "</a></b>";
} else {
echo 

<?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-author', true ) ) {
echo  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-author', true   ); 
} else {
echo get_the_author();
} ?>


} ?>
```

But I still can't wrap my head around how to get that working.

Comment: `<?php` is for when not in PHP. That tells the PHP processor where to start processing. `?>` is where it should stop processing. Everything inside those must be PHP, everything outside should not (you could have PHP outside but it won't be executed as PHP e.g. `?> echo "hello world";`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<?php 
if (get_the_author_meta('display_name') === 'daveMClaren') {
    echo "<b><a href='https://www.homepage.com/author/" . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . "'>" . esc_html(get_the_author()) . "</a></b>";
} else {
    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-author', true ) ) {
        echo  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-author', true   ); 
    } else {
        echo get_the_author();
    } 
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

if (get_the_author_meta('display_name') === 'daveMClaren') :

    echo "<b><a href='https://www.homepage.com/author/" . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . "'>" . esc_html(get_the_author()) . "</a></b>";
else :

    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-author', true ) ) :
        echo  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-author', true   ); 
    else :
        echo get_the_author();
    endif;    
    
endif;

?>
```